# subquery exercise

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I need to write a query that contains a subquery where it would list the name of departments and the number of employees per department having the word 'Representative' in their job_title and the list must be ordered by department_id.

I've written this query

```
SELECT d.department_name, emp.employee_id
FROM departments d, employees emp, jobs j
WHERE emp.department_id=d.department_id
AND j.job_title LIKE '%Representative%';
```

Comment: Besides for the subquery, you're missing some of the logic. How are `jobs` related to `departments` and `employees`?

Comment: please use sqlfiddle with your schema and records. Let us know expected output.

Comment: I'd move the part about the job title being like Representative to the subquery.

Comment: Presumably you're deleting the details on all of your questions when they're answered so that the professor can't Google for where you found them?

Answer (score 0):

If there is a requirement to use a subquery, then the following will achieve what you're looking for:

```
select   d.department_id,
         d.department_name,
         (select count(*)
          from   employees emp
          join   jobs j
          on     j.job_id = emp.employee_job -- I've made some assumptions, here!
          where  emp.department_id = d.department_id
          and    j.job_title like '%Representative%') reps
from     departments d
order by d.department_id;
```

Personally, however, I would use a query like this:

```
select   d.department_id,
         d.department_name,
         count(emp.employee_id) reps
from     departments d
join     employees emp
on       emp.department_id = d.department_id
join     jobs j
on       j.job_id = emp.employee_job -- Same assumption as before!
where    j.job_title like '%Representative%'
group by d.department_id,
         d.department_name
order by d.department_id;
```

I find it easier to read/interpret, but that's ultimately up to you.

Comment: Probably. You didn't specify in your original question, so I had to take a guess.

Answer (score 0):

There is some join logic missing in your example, but something like this may work for you:

```
select d.department_name, count(emp.employee_id)
from departments d, employees emp, jobs j
where j.job_title in (select job_title from jobs where job_title like '%Representative%')
group by d.department_name
```

The SQL may not be 100% correct but you can see the point.  it's hard to complete it without all of the join logic.

This should return you all of the department names and the employee count where the employee job title contains representative.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery for this. Use a simple `JOIN`.

```
  SELECT d.department_name, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM employee e JOIN department d
         ON e.department_id = d.department_id
    JOIN jobs j ON e.jobid = j.jobid
   WHERE j.job_title LIKE '%Representative%'
GROUP BY d.department_name
```

Or, if it is just an exercise for you, I would suggest using the following query:

```
SELECT d.department_name
       , (SELECT COUNT(e.*)
            FROM employees e JOIN jobs j ON e.jobid = j.jobid
           WHERE e.department_id = d.department_id
             AND j.job_title LIKE '%Representative%') AS cnt
  FROM departments d
```

In the real world, however, you code for convenience, not just for exercise. Your code should be convenient to read, understand and maintain for all those who are involved in your software development process. If it is just an exercise then you can use the second query. But if you have to use the query in a live application, the approach in the first query is better for everyone around you.

Comment: the "e.job_title" shouldn't it be j.job_title? because job_title is in the jobs table not in the employees

Comment: should the subquery be in the select clause or in a where clause?

Comment: In this case, it has to be in the `SELECT` clause.